# Multi-Language Intro Page for website

Tags: android

I am updating my current website and i need some advice...

Currently the Android Market is almost world wide.

Since there are many people visiting my site that speak all sorts of different languages, would it be effective to add an intro page that allows users to select there language?

For example when you type in intelsoftapps.com it will show a page that will come up with "Please select your language". when the user selects english it will go to the home English page. But if the user selects the chinese or french language it will go to the chinese page or the french page if selected.

Is this a good way to do this??

Sincerely,
IntelSoftApps

-

### [IntelSoftApps.com](http://intelsoftapps.com)

support@intelsoftapps.com

Answer (score 0):

You could just add Google translate to your website. I would imagine it works fine with Android for obvious reasons: http://translate.google.com/translate_tools